# How to read server side .json file from GWT client?

Tags: gwt, client

I am new to GWT. I have a file text.json on server. I need to read it on my GWT client. How to do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions here are about programming issues that should have source code involved. Please read "What topics can I ask about here" to learn more: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

I prefer gwt-jackson : https://github.com/nmorel/gwt-jackson
Works in a similar way to the normal java version.